# Swift 5 append to JSON file

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swift5

I'm developing an iOS in SwiftUI which has to capture the session data to JSON file. I am trying to append the data to the JSON file but I can only get to add 2 or 3 data at max. When I click a button to add, it overwrite the last entry.

Please help me fixt this. thanks

```
struct Item: Codable {
    var id: UUID
    var pid: String
    var date: String
    var startTime: String
    var endTime: String
}

@State var array: [Item] = {
    do {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            .appendingPathComponent("data.json")

        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let items = try decoder.decode([Item].self, from: data)
        return items
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return []
    }
}()

func writeJSON(items: [Item]) {
    do {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                .appendingPathComponent("data.json")

        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        try encoder.encode(array).write(to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

var body: some View {
 // Other codes
  Button("Add Session") {
    array.append(Items(id: UUID(), pid: pid, date: date, startTime: starttime, endTime: endtime))
    writeJSON(items: array)
  }

}
```

The follow is the JSON file, where the last entry is always overwritten with new data.

```
[{
    "startTime": "11:50:00",
    "id": "58DAF956-4DFA-496D-84DC-E1A78E4FEE84",
    "endTime": "11:50:00",
    "pid": "PID-0001",
    "date": "2022-01-10"
}, {
    "startTime": "11:50:00",
    "id": "BBD56ED2-29EB-4D1B-9AB0-D87562CDC4DB",
    "endTime": "11:51:00",
    "pid": "PID-0002",
    "date": "2022-01-10"
}, {
    "startTime": "11:51:00",
    "id": "E9214217-F77A-4A34-860D-846CB85F9986",
    "endTime": "11:51:00",
    "pid": "PID-0004",
    "date": "2022-01-10"
}]
```

Comment: Where is your code that "adds to the array"?

Comment: append happens upon button click which I've added into the view

Answer (score 0):

Your `array` property is a *computed variable*.  That means each time you reference `array` the code in the associated closure is executed and you get the current value from disk.

Try this:

```
func writeJSON(items: [Item]) {
    do {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                .appendingPathComponent("data.json")

        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        try encoder.encode(items).write(to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}


var body: some View {
 // Other codes
  Button("Add Session") {
    var newArray = array

    newArray.append(Items(id: UUID(), pid: pid, date: date, startTime: starttime, endTime: endtime))
    writeJSON(items: newArray)
  }

}
```

Comment: It is still the same and the last entry is replaced with newer data.

Comment: If I kill the app and restart and new entry added. But if I stay in the same screen and click "Add Session" then the last value is replaced. Also forgot to mention, there is an Alert confirmation to add the session. If the user press "Yes" then it should add. Is it something to do with that because the view isn't refreshing?